# How to make an appliacation go to fullscreen with a botton

Tags: android, android-studio

I search about this and this what i find

the code to make an application go to full screen is this

```
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN ;

View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

But when i put it in a button it doesn't work

My findings about the problems

The code only works when View is visible
You only can make it go to fullscreen every 1000 ms
The aplication clear automatically the flags when go to other part in the phone
My objective is to make the app go to full screen in all activities but i want to Know how it works the code above i search in the source code an i couldn't find a solution

The code above it works only when i upload the code to the phone

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: This doesnt answer my question